# Strategies for "Flexible Webservice"

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I am building webservices for many different clients to connect to a database of automotive parts. This parts have a wide variety of properties. Different clients will need different subsets of properties to 'do their thing.'

All clients will need at least an ID, a part number, and a name. Some might need prices, some might need URL's to images, etc. etc. The next client might be written years from now and require yet a different subset of properties. I'd rather not send more than they need.

I have been building separate 'PartDTO's' with subsets of properties for each of these requirements, and serving them up as separate webservice methods to return the same list of parts but with different properties for each one. Rather than build this up for each client and come up with logical names for the DTO's and methods, I'd like a way for the client to specify what they want. I'm returning JSON, so I was thinking about the client passing me a JSON object listing the properties they want in the result-set:

ret = { ImageUrl: true, RetailPrice: true, ... }

First off, does this make sense?

Second, What I'd rather not lose here is the nice syntax to return an IEnumerable < DTO > and let the JSON tools serialize it. I could certainly build up a 'JSON' string and return that, but that seems pretty kludgey.

Suggestions? C# 'dynamic'?

Comment: I have seen APIs (Jira is one) that let you specify the fields you want in the input. I think Jira uses a query param (expand they call it). Make it a comma separated list of field names. /v1/api/entity?fields=ImageUrl,RetailPrice  This way any given client can just request their particular subset of all of the fields.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good candidate for the [Entity-Attribute-Value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). Basically you have a table of ID, Name, Value and you allow each customer/facet to store whatever they want... Then when they query you return their name-value pairs and let them use them as they please.

PROS: super flexible. Good for situations where a strong schema adds tons of complexity vs value. Single endpoint for multiple clients.

CONS: Generally disliked pattern, very hard to select from efficiently and also hard to index. However, if all you do is store and return collections of name-value, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going the dictionary-route. I defined a base class:

```
public abstract DictionaryAsDTO<T> : IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>
{
    protected DictionaryAsDTO(T t, string listOfProperties)
    {
        // Populate an internal dictionary with subset of t's props based on string
    }
}
```

Then a DTO for Part like so:

```
public PartDTO : DictionaryAsDTO<Part>
{
    public PartDTO(Part p, string listOfProperties) : base(p, listOfProperties) {}

    // Override method to populate base's dictionary with Part properties based on
    // listOfProperties
}
```

Then I wrote a JSON.NET converter for DictionaryAsDTO which emits JSON-y object-properties instead of key-value-pairs.

The web service builds an IEnumerable based on queries that return IEnumerable and serializes them.

Viola!