# How can I serialize a class that implements IDictionary with Newtonsoft.JSON?

Tags: json, serialization, dictionary

I am pulling out my hair again. I am working thru possible solutions to my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618342/strategies-for-flexible-webservice). I have this class:

```
public class PartViewDTO : IDictionary<string, object>
{
    ...
}
```

It is constructed with the details of what fields it should represent - Name, PartNumber, Price, etc. etc.

I am trying to serialize a collection of PartViewDTO's as a response for a web service but I don't want the traditional-dictionary serialization of

```
[ { "Key": "Key1", "Value": "Value1" }, ...]
```

Instead I want

```
{ "Key1": "Value1", ... }
```

I have tried several variations on applying the JsonDictionaryAttribute to this class:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonDictionary(ItemTypeNameHandling=Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Objects)]
public class PartViewDTO : IDictionary<string, object>
```

But at run-time I get an exception thrown that "PartViewDTO is not a dictionary"

Bottom line - PartViewDTO is a dictionary but I want it to serialize like the keys in the dictionary were properties on the class. I'm returning an IEnumerable < PartViewDTO > of these from web services so I'm hoping an attribute applied to the class itself will clue JSON in on how it should be serialized.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out JSON.NET does a fine job serializing dictionaries the way I want. The problem is it doesn't recognize that my type IS a dictionary. I ended up writing a custom converter for PartViewDTO which did the dictionary-thing.

All is well now!